# Migrating ZSQLProcessor.Script.Text from ZeosLib to FireDAC for MySQL

Tags: delphi, firedac, zeos

Was trying to migrate app to FireDAC usage on Delphi 10.2 and stuck only with this function:
[Source on github](https://github.com/Faq/Truice/blob/master/MainUnit.pas#L13218)

```
   procedure TMainForm.ExecuteScript(script: string; memo: TMemo);
var
  Log: TStringList;
  FN: string;
begin
  ShowHourGlassCursor;
  ZSQLProcessor.Script.Text := script;
  try
    ZSQLProcessor.Connection.StartTransaction;
    ZSQLProcessor.Execute;
    ZSQLProcessor.Connection.Commit;
  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      ZSQLProcessor.Connection.Rollback;
      memo.Text := E.Message;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
```

**Stuck with line** and was not able to get along, any help would be good:

```
ZSQLProcessor.Script.Text := script;
```

reference:
[ZSqlProcessor.pas](https://github.com/GabrielF7/ZeosLib/blob/testing-7.3/src/component/ZSqlProcessor.pas)

Converted function without last part looks so:

```
procedure TMainForm.ExecuteScript(script: string; memo: TMemo);
var
  Log: TStringList;
  FN: string;
begin
  ShowHourGlassCursor;
  //ZSQLProcessor.Script.Text := script;
  try
    MyTrinityConnection.StartTransaction;
    FDScript1.ValidateAll;
    FDScript1.ExecuteAll;
    MyTrinityConnection.Commit;
  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      MyTrinityConnection.Rollback;
      memo.Text := E.Message;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Btw. there's more to improve here. FireDAC has its own waiting cursors, but better consider asynchronous mode or worker thread for this task (anyway, that cursor seem to never change back). The `try..finally` block should be in pseudocode like `Transaction.Start; try DoWork; Transaction.Commit; except Transaction.Rollback end;`. You can handle more detailed exceptions and you don't need to `Exit` from the method in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign single SQL script to the [**TFDScript**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDScript) object you can simply [**Add**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDSQLScripts.Add) one [**TFDSQLScript**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDSQLScript) item to the [**TFDSQLScripts**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDSQLScripts) collection and set its [**SQL**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDSQLScript.SQL) string list collection text to the SQL command of your choice, for example:

```
FDScript1.SQLScripts.Add.SQL.Text := script; { ← this adds one TFDSQLScript item to the script collection and to this just added item assigns a SQL script }
```

Of course, this assumes the [**TFDSQLScripts**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDSQLScripts) collection is clear, if not call [**Clear**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TCollection.Clear) before.

Comment: You're welcome! Just keep in mind clearing that collection if you're about to call that method multiple times.